# Show product commerce by taxonomy parent with childs

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce, views

I want to show several products filtered by apples. Apple is a hierarchy taxonomy and not always the values from the parents are in the childs.

**Example:**
apple (apple can have other results that are not in big_apple nor small_aplle)
-big_apple
-small_apple

**Question:** How can I create a view that when it's 'fruit/apple' shows apple + big_apple + small_apple and whent  it's 'fruit/big_apple' it will only be 'big_apple' ?

I think with this in contextual filters can help but it's far from working:

```
$id= taxonomy_get_term_by_name($argument);
$children = array_keys(taxonomy_get_children($id));
if(!empty($children))
{
    $handler->argument .= '+' . implode('+', $children);
    return TRUE;
}else
    return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am my most popular fan so I will answer myself:

**1.** It's not possible to add that PHP code to the view, as **it's a known bug** that the view doesn't allow multiple contextual filter variables as a PHP. Although you can use them through the URL and changing the 'code PHP' option by 'Multiple Terms ID separated by ',' OR '+''. --> I don't like that option as the URL won't be very clean and can be a bit complicated.

**2.** **Found a better option!!** I decided to select the parent when one of its childs are selected. This option can be activated as automatically, when installing the [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module:

> **About this module**
>
> This module provides an expandable tree widget for the Taxonomy Term Reference field in Drupal 7. This widget is intended to serve as a replacement for Drupal's core Taxonomy Term Reference widget, which is a flat list of radio buttons or checkboxes and not necessarily fit for medium to large taxonomy trees.

**Note:** I don't know why but my tree view is not as nice as in the picture and I needed to use a fix but it works perfect.